# C-language binary shift operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to learn some basic C for a project. 
On the Wikipedia article on binary shift operators:

> If the variable ch contains the bit pattern 11100101, then ch >> 1 will produce the result 01110010, and ch >> 2 will produce 00111001.

Just for clarification, will the last digit of the binary operator be lost if you shift it to the right (>>1)? It won't rotate to the front, like in a circular array, correct?

Comment: *C (ancient stuff)* - Are you trying to insult? :) Yes, the shifted out bit is lost. There is no circular rotation in C

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: tbh I love the stuff but whenever I look for tutorials they're always littered with super old documentation or C++ equivalents. Also Visual Studio has been giving me hell just for trying to compile C code (which was most surprising thing)

Comment: Think of it as division by a power of two. The remainder gets lost.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a good choice for the latest C standards.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: at least for positive numbers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what do you recommend instead? I too, have been using VIsual Studio for C99 and C11.

Comment: So you're asking whether Wikipedia is correct on this?  It's not altogether unreasonable to do so, but if you accept it as correct then it already answers your question (in the affirmative, and it *is* correct).

Comment: @Rizzo The most common and standard-defining choice would be `GCC`. I don't understand how can you use VS with C99 and C11 given it is not supporting them.

Comment: @Rizzo, since VS does not support all of C99 or C2011, you have *not* been using it for those languages.  Presumably, you have been using it for the C dialect it does support, but you'll eventually get yourself into trouble if you confuse that with *bona fide*, full C99 or C2011.

Comment: @EugeneSh. my mistake. Would Visual Studio 2015 be suitable for basic C coding which covers most of C99 ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the holy word of C (the C standard) says about bitshifts to the right:

[6.5.7p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
> an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
> the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 /
> 2<sup>E2</sup> . If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
> value is implementation-defined.

In other words:
`x>>n` == `x/two_to_the(n)`, though that may not be the case if `x<0`

(To answer even more directly, yes — when you divide, the least significant bits are lost).

Comment: Right. That is interesting, actually, because what if it was say the thing you mentioned, a signed char that was a negative number? (say -2). I'm guessing implementation defined just means based on what IDE or framework you are using

Comment: @KevinHu The difference between implementation defined and undefined is that you *should never* invoke or rely on the undefined behavior, while you can assume a specific implementation defined behavior, given you code does not need to be portable and your compiler implementation is doing what you need.

Comment: @KevinHu Then it's implementation-defined, which is why it might be a better idea to use actual division there (optimizers tend to be smart enough to notice you're dividing by a constant that's a power of two, in which case they'll turn the operation into an assembly-level bitshift).

Comment: @KevinHu, "implementation defined" means the C language implementation -- effectively the compiler and associated runtime support -- gets to choose, and furthermore that it must document that choice.  The behavior is reliable for that implementation.  And yes, if you want to ensure portability across implementations, then you must avoid relying on implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see. implementation defined is also something that deals with unsigned and signed as well, correct? I believe if you do not specify the signage then the implementation will do it for you (which is less memory intensive but more dangerous)

Comment: @KevinHu Signedness comes along with a type, and the implementation can choose an integer type for your integer literal depending on its size and radix. The rules are in http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1 . But this is kind of an "advanced topic". I think it's better to learn some basic C first before dealing with these finer points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The shift operation `x >> 1` will result in a value equal to `x` divided by 2 if `x` is unsigned or positive, and is implementation-defined if `x` is negative (C.2011 §6.5.7 ¶5).

Answer (score 1):

Right, the outermost bit will be lost unless you save its value before shifting:

```
unsigned char ch = 229; 
int lostBit = ch & 0x01;
ch >>= 1;
```

Note that bit shift operator `>>` is defined only for unsigned or positive values. In your example, if `ch` were a signed char, a value `11100101` actually represented a negative number (-27) and the operation would yield undefined behaviour.